# empty $_POST and $_FILE variable when uploading large files

Tags: php

I was trying to upload a file which is 20MB in size. Now default form upload size is 8MB. When I upload such a file i get $_POST and $_FILE variables empty. Now I want to put a check on file size. If I get both these variables empty, how can I put such a check ?? Please give me suggestions

Comment: And...what's your php.ini upload limit?

Comment: Surely the browser won't even submit the form if the form upload limit is set below the size of the file you are trying to upload, as this is a client side check... Even if it does, note that the files are found in `$_FILES`, not `$_FILE` - is this your problem, or just a typo? Note also that even if the upload is successful, `$_POST` *will* be empty if the only thing in the form is a file input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what you actually want. But you can probe the recieved content size using:

```
  $_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]
```

This should tell how big the POST request body would have been. (The number might be higher than the actual received content, in case of an aborted upload.)

Answer (score 4):

Barring any code errors, its most likely your `20MB` exceeds your upload limit.
Change this permanently from your `php.ini` file.

Use

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "30M");
```

to set your max upload size for that session only.  And for POST

Use this

```
ini_set("post_max_size", "30M");
```

To check the sizes

```
   echo ini_get("post_max_size") . "\n";
   echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
```

Comment: You should not upvote your own posts, that's considered against rules here, and you could be banned. You know what I'm talking about

Comment: @genesis OK. Sorry, wouldn't do that again.

Comment: @genesis Yep. How can I join the accounts  or delete one?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout php://input, the allowed 8mb part of it should be there.

For example `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically set your max file size for upload.

write down below statement in your upload function where you are trying to upload file.
this will enhance limit up to 50 MB

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "50M");
```

If you want to check file variables, you can user alternative HTTP_POST_FILES

```
$theFileSize = $HTTP_POST_FILES['file']['size'];
```

Hope this may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: my upload fails along with post. I checked both $_FILES and $_POST variables. Both would contain nothing. even $HTTP_POST_FILES fails

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX_FILE_SIZE` as a hidden input field, this will stop the user waiting if the file is larger than the limit and won't execute your code so the variables won't be empty...

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the
>   file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by
>   PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the
>   trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that
>   it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this
>   setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with
>   a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a
>   convenience feature for users on the client side of the application.
>   The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however,
>   cannot be fooled.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: What browsers make use of the hidden field?

Comment: All browsers use the hidden field, it get's sent along with the form.

Comment: Unless you mean what browsers understand the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` field in which case the answer is that it's a server-side check, PHP will stop the script if the uploaded file size reaches that size. The difference is that PHP can check it from the buffer as it's uploading rather than waiting for the entire file to be uploaded before you know it's full size.

Comment: I don't understand.. if this is a server-side check, why would PHP not look at the ini setting and just use that instead?